# modify per-application access control for private key via command line?

Tags: xcode, macos, security, command-line, keychain

I have a cert in a key chain that contains a private key.  I'd like to add an application to the access control "white list" for that key.  I know how to do this using the graphical key chain tool, but I'd like to do it via the command line as part of an Xcode build script.

From what I can tell the "security" command is the way to manipulate key chains at the command line, but I can't figure out from the man page how I'd go about accomplishing this task.

For completeness, here's exactly what I do in the key chain tool that I'd like to do via the command line:

1. Click the cert to show its private key.
2. Right-click the private key and select the "Get Info" menu item.
3. Click the "Access Control" tab.
4. Click the "+" button to add an application to the white list.
5. Select the application (in my case Xcode) and click "Add".

I might also be interested in how to allow access to all applications.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is any way from `security` to do this *after* the key was imported. However, if you're importing the key for the first time, you can use the `-T` flag:

```
 -T  Specify an application which may access the imported key 
     (multiple -T options are allowed)
```

So in my case I was able to do this:

```
security import my.key -P mypassword -T /usr/bin/pkgbuild
```

And everything worked!

Comment: this is great, but it doesn't actually answer the question. Provided that I have already imported the private key (along with a certificate associated with it) and now I want to allow my app access to that private-key, programmatically? how can I do it? many times (in corporate environments) the certificates are deployed en-mass in advance, by IT guys, and I only need to let my application use them. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**

I'm honest this is probably not the best place to post this... but I stumbled onto this (and several other) entries with more or less the same problem. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34388302/359100. But since I found a solution which could help other people who try to change access control for private key in Keychain via remote session my solution could help...

B/c for me importing via CLI *did not* work (using `-T` or `-A`). I always got that pop regarding access from Keychain.

BTW: If you know a better SO answer where this belongs... please let me know or move it there...

**Solution**

Create a Keychain on your *local* machine. E.g. name it apple-development[.keychain]. Add there your private keys and assign necessary access control (best: "Allow all ..."). Now copy that keychain to your remote Mac and add it there via Keychain application (File / Add Keychain...). For CI you maybe do something like this:

```
security unlock-keychain -p YOUR-KEYCHAIN-PASSWORD "${HOME}/apple-development.keychain"
```