# code sign wants to sign using key - Doesn't allow or always allow but deny works

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, code-signing, xcode7.2

I'm trying to build and archive the application. After compiling, an alert window appears requesting the "`codesign wants to sign using key "my account Name" in your keychain`" and the buttons `Always Allow`, `Deny` and `Allow`, when i press `Always allow` or `allow`, nothing happens, only `deny` works.

I enabled the "`Allow all applications to access this item`" in private key info but it didn't worked for me.

I'm using VNC remote Mac (El Capitan) and Xcode 7.2 .I'm not using any third party utilities and i did not install any mouse related apps.

I have tried below links

[Having issue with allowing codesign to use my keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667704/having-issue-with-allowing-codesign-to-use-my-keychain/34388302)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25092

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212622/keychain-wont-let-copy-passwords-after-10-11-1-update

I'd like know reason behind this issue and how can i resolve it ?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do build and archive from command line? Is your key chain(login) unlocked?

Comment: No, I'm archiving through Xcode like Xcode/Product/Archiving and my login key chain is unlocked

Comment: I have the same issue, but mine is requesting a password for the key chain. I don't know any password.

Answer (score 28):

Had the same problem, tried many things and it felt like total voodoo. One of these two eventually solved the problem for me:

- Got rid of all expired/revoked certificates in my Keychain Access.
- Locked my `login` keychain in Keychain Access (it then prompted me for password for unlocking.)

Hope this helps anybody!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I think all I needed to do was to lock my login keychain, I didn't delete my expired certs.

Comment: retarded, but true. Even created new login keychain and re-imported certs etc. Seems the system prompt fails when the keychain is presently unlocked. thanks for figuring this out and posting!

Comment: WOW, this helped!

Answer (score 19):

Enter your mac user password and hit **Always Allow**.

Comment: Entering the mac user password is what did it. For 2 hours I kept entering my developer password. They need to be more clear with that, smh. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Please don't press "Allow"
press "Always allow" only

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it on the machine itself, closing all the vnc connections.
Mac determines the click originates from the connected devices nor from any remote controlled device.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Xcode and trying again fixed it for me. :/

Answer (score 0):

I logged in as root (go to your terminal su -). It allowed me to select "Always Allow". This in return enabled me to archive and upload my build to the app store.