# Code sign wants to sign using key in your keychain

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing, keychain

I want to generate my build so that I have started following steps as like, I was doing from last few years. But this time following dialog box come in front of me while I try to export the build:

[image]

I have used Google for solution of this problem and tried multiple given suggestions but still I can't able to sort out this problem.

Here is the main reference that I found on stackoverflow:
[code sign wants to sign using key - Doesn't allow or always allow but deny works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592377/code-sign-wants-to-sign-using-key-doesnt-allow-or-always-allow-but-deny-works)

But those reply not working for me so please share your suggestion with me.

Comment: Clicking on "Always Allow" not working?

Comment: No just again and again popup coming...

Comment: Add the system password or admin password and click on "Always Allow"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be something funny with the Trust setting in the certificate.

1. Open Keychain.
2. Find the relevant certificate in "My Certificates". Verify it hasn't expired.
3. Double click to open.
4. Doof with the *When using this certificate* field. Setting it to **Always Trust** before building might help. You can flip it back to **Use System defaults** after.
5. Also check the settings on the **Code Signing** specific field. That might be wrong.

[image]

This might have happened if you pressed "Deny" at some point in the past.

Comment: I think this answer worked for me because majorly I done this change within Keychain through I require to switch back to Use System Defaults because Always Trusts build was not accepted by Apple store.